# Cross-Browser SVG Text Baseline Alignment

Tags: html, svg, cross-browser

[image: Chrome SVG Render Screenshot]

This is how SVG text is rendered in browser for Chrome with the following (note in react so camel case attributes)

```
            <text x="50%" y="50%"
                    className='middleText'
                    textAnchor="middle"
                    alignmentBaseline="middle"
                    >{style.displayVal.toFixed(precision)}</text>
```

This is how the text renders in Firefox:

[image: Firefox SVG Render Screenshot]

What is the best way you've found to get consistent baseline crossbrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace alignmentBaseline with dominantBaseline.

Firefox does not currently support the former property but does support the latter.