# Getting SVG text to align based on top left in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

MDN seems to say to use [`text-anchor="start"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor) and [`alignment-baseline="hanging"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline) but that doesn't seem to be working for me. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<svg viewBox="-1.1 -1.1 2.2 2.2" width="150" height="150">
  <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="red" />
  <text x="-1" y="-1" text-anchor="start" alignment-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 0.6px;">TEST</text>
</svg>
<p>"TEST" should be inside the red box at the top left?</p>
```

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090439/cross-browser-svg-text-baseline-alignment) says to use `dominant-baseline` but that doesn't work either

```html
<svg viewBox="-1.1 -1.1 2.2 2.2" width="150" height="150">
  <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="red" />
  <text x="-1" y="-1" text-anchor="start" dominant-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 0.6px;">TEST</text>
</svg>
<p>"TEST" should be inside the red box at the top left?</p>
```

Results for dominant-baseline in Chrome

[image]

Results in dominant-baseline Firefox

[image]

The strange thing is [the live example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline) seems to work with `alignment-baseline` works in Chrome but (a) it doesn't work for me and (b) it doesn't work in Firefox

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be [a bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1013859) if the font size is too small

If I change the font size to 1px it works. Below 1px it fails

```html
<svg viewBox="-1.1 -1.1 2.2 2.2" width="150" height="150">
  <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="red" />
  <text x="-1" y="-1" text-anchor="start" dominant-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 0.6px;">TEST</text>
</svg>
<span>0.6px</span>

<svg viewBox="-1.1 -1.1 2.2 2.2" width="150" height="150">
  <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="red" />
  <text x="-1" y="-1" text-anchor="start" dominant-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 1px;">TEST</text>
</svg>
<span>1px</span>

<svg viewBox="-1.1 -1.1 2.2 2.2" width="150" height="150">
  <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="red" />
  <text x="-1" y="-1" text-anchor="start" dominant-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 0.4pt;">TEST</text>
</svg>
<span>0.4pt</span>
```

Results in Firefox and Safari

[image]

Results in Chrome

[image]

I'm guessing I can work around it by making the fonts larger. I chose the viewbox to be basically 2 units since the math I was doing meant I could just set values in the SVG in the -1 to +1 range which was the range of the values I was plotting so no math required to apply the values. Changing the viewBox size I'll have to add math but it should work around this issue

Comment: Haha, you ninja'ed me with answer to your own question :). Anyway, `text-anchor="start"` should not to be needed, as that's the default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MDN's `alignment-baseline` example does not work in Firefox here too. But `dominant-baseline` does work. Which seems to confirm info from their page:

> For object alignment in other elements (such as `<text>`), see dominant-baseline.

As for the SVG itself, you're trying to squeeze text under 1px, and that seems to make text disappear. If you remove `font-size` part, you should see top left corner of a huge letter "T" there.

It looks like font cannot go under 1px size. So, instead of working with a bit strange coordinates ranging from -1 to 2.2, try to use "easy" stuff (at least until you get the text rendered in correct place):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 15 15" width="150" height="150">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="15" height="15" fill="red" />
  <text x="0" y="0" alignment-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 5px">TEST</text>
</svg>
<p>"TEST" should be inside the red box at the top left?</p>
```

That should at least render the "TEST" text in Chrome. It does not work in Firefox.

Here's your second snippet, with fixed coordinates, working in both Chrome and Firefox:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 15 15" width="150" height="150">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="15" height="15" fill="red" />
  <text x="0" y="0" dominant-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 5px;">TEST</text>
</svg>
<p>"TEST" should be inside the red box at the top left?</p>
```

You'll notice that i did not use `text-anchor="start"`. That's because, at least according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor, `start` is default, so example renders as if it was set that way.